Differences in symmetry group of a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^3$ vs. $\mathbb{R}^2$?
Given a regular triangle in the xy-plane with corners in
$(1,0,0); (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},0);(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},0)$,
show that the symmetry group $G \subset O(3)$  of this triangle is isomorphic to $D_3 \times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z)}$.
I'm trying to understand how G is different from the symmetry group of this triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $D_3$. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, I can additionally reflect points through planes. In this specific case, the reflection of the triangle through the xy-plane is a symmetry operation, since it doesn't do anything. But this is only because z=0.
Say this triangle was "hovering" above the xy-plane (e.g. z=1 for all corners), then reflecting through the xy-plane would no longer pose a symmetry operation, because the reflection would sit 1 unit below the xy-plane, correct? What would the symmetry group be in this case, i.e. generally, what additional operations do I gain by going from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R^3}$?

Normally one does not consider $\mathbf{O}(2)$ to be a subgroup of $\mathbf{O}(3)$, since $2\times2$ matrices are not $3\times3$ matrices. However there is a fairly natural embedding (injective group morphism) $\mathbf{O}(2)\hookrightarrow\mathbf{O}(3)$, namely by extending the matrix with a third column and row taken from the $3\times3$ identity matrix. In this setting one can compare the image of the subgroup $D_3$ of $\mathbf O(2)$ with the symmetry group of the triangle inside $\mathbf O(3)$; I imagine this question should be taken in that sense.

Also, by only considering the linear groups $\mathbf O(n)$, one is only considering symmetries that fix the origin (in addition to fixing the triangle). This means that if you translate the equilateral triangle in such a way that its barycentre is no longer the origin, you get fewer symmetries, often just the identity. This is true both in dimension $2$ and in dimension $3$. It would then be more natural to work in the affine orthogonal groups (all isometries), i.e., throw in translations together with linear isometries.

You should start with the definition of the symmetry group of a subset $T\subset X$ used in this problem. Is it the subgroup of isometries of $X$ preserving $T$? Then the reason for the extra $Z_2$ is that the symmetry group of a triangle $T$ in $R^3$ does not act effectively on $T$ (unlike in the case of $R^2$). The extra $Z_2$ is the kernel of the action, regardless of the location of the triangle.

I suspect that what's happening here is that in $\Bbb R^3$, there is a distinction between $180^\circ$ rotation about the $x$ axis and reflection across the $xz$ plane. But in $\Bbb R^2$ (presumably seen as the $xy$ plane in $\Bbb R^3$), those two are indistinguishable.

I think the following should address your questions in a more general setting. Given a figure in a plane inside a $3$-dimensional Euclidean space. Every symmetry of the plane can be extended naturally to a symmetry of the whole space be requiring that the latter still preserve distances (is an isometry), and preserve the side of the plane that points outside the plan lie on (rather than switch sides). Without the second part of the condition, there would be two ways to extend, which differ by a reflection with respect to the plane. As a consequence, the symmetries of the $3$-dimensional Euclidean space that conserve the figure form a group twice as large as the of the symmetries of the plane with that property.
